# Javascript : Can't retrieve value from array

Tags: javascript

I have a code

```
alert(JSON.stringify((this.shop.get('selectedOrder')).get('orderLines')));
```

The Result look like this

```
[{"cart_weight":0,"total_weight":1,"quantity":1,"list_price":1,"discount":0,"ean13":false,"product_image_small":false,"name":"Watermelon1","pos_categ_id":[1,"Others"],"taxes_id":[],"id":2}]
```

When I run this code

```
alert((this.shop.get('selectedOrder')).get('orderLines').total_weight);
```

The result become

```
undefined
```

Any export can help ?

I suspect is the double bracket causing the issue [{ }], but I am new to javascript. Not able to solve the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: try `get('orderLines')[0].total_weight``

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try `alert((this.shop.get('selectedOrder').get('orderLines')[0].total_weight);`

As you suspect, your result is not an object (in javascript terminology, any data between `{}`) but an array (`[]`) containing one object. So you have to access the first element of your array before accessing the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your selected order has multiple lines.  You need to choose which line to get the `total_weight` from.  In this case, there is only one line - so you can reference this using `[0]`.  I.E.:

```
alert((this.shop.get('selectedOrder')).get('orderLines')[0].total_weight);
```

If instead, for example, you needed to calculate the weight of the entire order, you could iterate over all the order lines, and calculate the sum.